# Is using a USB sound card still better than the onboard jack?

Tags: usb, audio

Back in the day of the Raspberry Pi 1 B+, if you didn't want to route audio through the HDMI cable it was a good idea to use a USB sound card, because audio out of the headphone jack tended to get a little scratchy. Is this still the case with the Raspberry Pi 3 B+?

Comment: I have used USB-powered speakers with my Pi 3B and they are scratchy. When I use a different set of wall-powered speakers there is no scratchiness. So at least in my case it appears the scratchiness is on the USB power line, *not* on the audio signal, so using a USB-powered converter actually makes it worse. Of course, it also could just be that I have one pair of crap speakers.

Comment: I have a raspberry Pi 2, tried both onboard jack and a USB sound dongle. The USB sound dongle definitely gives better sound and does not have problems like "hissing" when nothing is playing, or mono sound etc. I do use that pi as a upnp renderer with the USB sound dongle now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Judging by schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md) the audio output circuit has not changed. It is definitely the same in Pi3 and Pi2, however in Pi1 this portion is omitted from the public schematics, but I have no reason to believe its different.

[image]

This is a very simple audio output circuit that smooths PWM from the CPU through a **bandpass filter** @ 33Hz-15KHz.

Additionally this shares a ground with other portions of the board, and there is digital noise and supply noise that is induced onto the output.

You may get slightly better fidelity with a cleaner power supply, but a dedicated audio output device is still your best bet.

---

**Circuit Details**

There Two Channels, references for **L** channel

- `R49`, `R60` is a divider used to take `3.3V` logic to `2.5V`ish,
- `U11` is an ONSemi NC7WZ16 ([datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NC7WZ16-D.pdf)) fast buffer (x1 Amplifier) with characteristics suitable for fast PWM.
- `R16,R17,C59,C58` form the bandpass filter `33.9Hz`-`15.9KHz`

  - `R16`+`C59` form the low-pass portion of the bandpass, at `15.9KHz` cutoff
  - `R17`+`C58` form the high-pass portion of the bandpass, with `33.9Hz` cutoff
- `J7` is the output jack
- `D4` is actually a protection diode for the composite video out, quietly visible only as net label `COMPVID`

Comment: [The Foundation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-1-model-b/) claims for the Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+: "Better audio. The audio circuit incorporates a dedicated low-noise power supply." which I read as an improvment over the original Pi-1B (pre 2014).

Comment: @Ghanima I suspect this may be the `AUD_2V5` power bus referenced in the schematic. Supply noise from other sources can be coupled through the ground as well.

Answer (score 5):

After some quick testing: yes. Plugging an audio cable directly into the jack results in a fair amount of variable white noise coming out of the speakers. Using a USB sound card works beautifully to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you intend to use it for, but the on-board audio is definitely "not hifi". For a beep or voice prompt, it may be fine. Your most obvious options are:

1. Use HDMI out if you have an amp, receiver, adaptor 
   or TV that will accept it. Clean, and cheap solution if it works for you.
2. Use a USB sound card. These are cheap but do add to the clutter a bit.
3. Use a DAC, usually in the form of a HAT module mounted on the RPi. A bit more compact and clean, and high quality audio. A lot of options for on-board amps and connector types.

Comment: USB sound cards also vary in quality.  If possible, use the USB-adapters that come with a good headset.  They also tend to be small.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the Raspberry Pi audio is not top-notch quality. However, the answer to your questions also depends on the USB sound card. [I've found](https://www.spinellis.gr/blog/20151213/) that a low-end USB sound card suffers from the same problems as the Raspberry Pi.